# javafx SplitPane devider jumps when content/children change

Tags: javafx

I have some trouble preventing the SplitPane devider from jumping once one of the two children changes is size. In my SplitPane are two children, one on the left and one on the right. The one on the left is a TreeView. Everytime I expand one Item in the tree, the devider moves to the right, because the TreeView becomes wider.

Is there a way to prevent this resizing without loosing the option for a user to change the devider?

Comment: Just a guess here but `SplitPane` normally use `AnchorPane` as the root node for each side. Try changing the  left root node to a `ScrollPane`.

Comment: The left Node is actually not a TreeView directly. The TreeView is inside a VBox with a Button.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).